# Constructing piecewise function from changepoints in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, piecewise

I want to construct a piecewise function from changepoints in python. I expect my inputs and outputs to be large, so speed is important.

Input:

- int numpy array: `A = [1,7, 1000, 1500]`
- bool numpy array: `B = [True, False, True, True, False, True, False, False]` where the length of `A` is equal to the number of `True` in `B`

Output:

- int numpy array: `C = [1, 1, 7, 1000, 1000, 1500, 1500, 1500]` where the length of `C` is the same as the length of `B`

Essentially each element of `A` is repeated until the next `True` in `B` shows up in which case the next element of `A` is used.

Comment: Please look at this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be handy to lift your quality up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [1]: import numpy

In [2]: A = numpy.array([1, 7, 1000, 1500])

In [3]: B = numpy.array([True, False, True, True, False, True, False, False])

In [4]: A[B.cumsum() - 1]
Out[4]: array([   1,    1,    7, 1000, 1000, 1500, 1500, 1500])
```

`B.cumsum() - 1` computes which element of A to use for each element of the output, and then `A[B.cumsum() - 1]` extracts those elements. You could probably also work out a way to use `numpy.repeat` to do this.